Batch Request for the last 30 days in Great Expectations
I want to run GX validations for a SQL database data source recurrently using the 30 days of data. If I use a query data asset, I would need to create a new data asset with a customized date range every time I validate the data (as least as far as I understand). On the other hand, if I use a table data asset, I could use add_splitter_datetime_part() function to slice a data asset for a batch request. However, with add_splitter_datetime_part() I can only filter for specific days, month or year, and not for a dynamic date interval, like 'last 30 days'. Is there any other function that would work for that scenario, or is there a way to use add_splitter_datetime_part() in that way? I checked the documentation, but it is not clear to me the best way to do this.
